# Do we really need the [characters] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination

Do we really need the [characters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/characters) tag? Going through some of the questions, I can't seem to figure out what, if anything, this tag is adding that makes these questions distinct. It seems like a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Do we need this tag? If not, can we have Charizard use *Fire Blast* to burninate it?